# How to include a normal inverse function power Pivot DAX?

Tags: dax

I am interested in calculating confidence intervals in PowerPivot using DAX. Unfortunately the formula editor doesn't show a NORM.INV function.

Is this formula included in PowerPivot DAX?

Here's the formula I tried:

`=Norm.Inv(.9, 0, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the DAX statistical functions, read the docs: [NORM.INV](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/norm-inv-dax)

[image]